# Elastic search pattern replace for set of words

Tags: elasticsearch, pattern-matching, token

I have a requirement of splitting date pattern into set of words. for example if I have a date with pattern "2015-02-22T14:12:12" in the document for a date field.
I have broken this word into below set of words using pattern token filter in elastic search,

```
--> 2015-02-22T14:12:12,
--> 2015-02-22,
--> 2015-02
--> 02-22,
--> 02,
--> 22
```

Now I should be able to pass these tokens to some other token filter , so that I should be able to replace token "2015-02-22" with "2015-FEB-22","2015-FEBRUARY-22" and "2015-02" with "2015-FEB","2015-FEBRUARY".

How could I effectively use the available token filters to preserve original and generate new tokens as above. or is there any chance in elastic search that I can write custom filters? if yes , any documentation related to custom token filters is very thankful to me.

Comment: Maybe [pattern_replace token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html)? Do you want your users to search for "february" and to match 2016-02?

Comment: @AndreiStefan yes. and using pattern_replace token filter we cant replace multiple words. for example , we may replace Febrauary for 02, but has to replace march for 03.....etc. for this I need to add list of pattern_replace token filter and is there kind of any reg expression for this to replace at runtime?

Comment: What is the reason to replace that? and why not to controll that you your app? because in my oppinion ES should not be responsibe for such kind business logic